# Use an already existing Google map for android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an app that would use a Google map to show a lot of custom waypoints.

I know that you can add these markers in your code but there are far too many to do this manually. This map already exists but as far as I can tell from searching there doesn't seem to be a way to use this map.

Comment: no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @tyczj There is a google map with custom overlays that I would like to use in an app. But I don't know how to put the map with the overlays into the app. I can put a generic app in but not with the overlays. To clarify these overlays are custom pointers to show places that would otherwise not be on the map.

Comment: @user3112422 i suggest you update the query.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a map somewhere with the markers all loaded and you just want to add them to your view?

Comment: @Rani Yes. That's about it.

Comment: If that loaded map uses Google Maps Android API then I think you can. But if it is a web api you can't. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rani Thanks I was unsure and didn't want to go ahead unless I knew. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3112422 I'm not sure. What api does the pre loaded map uses?